# Managing sessions with C/CGI

Tags: c, cgi

I'm looking towards writing some applications with C and CGI, and now that I've implemented basic functions like URI encode/decode, HTML entities encode/decode, query/cookie parser, etc. I need to manage sessions. How should I do this? For example, how does PHP manage sessions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the UserID and SessionID in a cookie, then store all other data on the server in a database. Do not encode user and session in the url as this leads to session-hijacking even if the user only wants to show some friend a link.

Comment: Thanks. Should I 'trim'/'clean' old sessions? If so, how? I'd imagine that hardly anyone actually cleanly ends their session by requesting a logout page.

Comment: Yes that is a common problem. The session-entries in your database have to have a time-value which you update on every action the session performs. Then you can run an automated job in the database which cleans out all sessions that are unresponsive for e.g. more than 1 hour.

Answer (score 5):

As HTTP is stateless, you have to maintain an id that can track your session. The two main ways are to use cookies to store the id or to embed the id in the URL, usually doing URL rewriting.

You can have a look at [WT](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) which is a web toolkit written in C++. see also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746309/which-is-the-best-c-web-framework) for a list of c++ web framework. you will probably find how they handle sessions.

my2c